# TypeScript / Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Snackbar'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, snackbar

I want to use the Snackbar [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) component in my React app.
For the record, my app is written in TypeScript.

I am having issues when trying to import the component. The import line says:

> Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Snackbar'.ts(2440)

Then in the render method, when I try to use it, the IDE says:

> 'Snackbar' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Snackbar'?ts(2749).

Is [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) trolling me? (A friend at my work tried the same code and it worked.)

The code I tried to use is [here](https://material-ui.com/es/components/snackbars/#simple-snackbars).

This is my setup:

```
  System:
    OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.19.1 - /usr/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.5.4 - /usr/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 88.0.4324.150
    Firefox: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @material-ui/core: ^4.11.0 => 4.11.0
    @material-ui/icons: ^4.9.1 => 4.9.1
    @material-ui/styles:  4.10.0
    @material-ui/system:  4.9.14
    @material-ui/types:  5.1.0
    @material-ui/utils:  4.10.2
    @types/react: ^16.9.41 => 16.9.52
    react: ^16.13.1 => 16.14.0
    react-dom: ^16.13.1 => 16.14.0
    typescript: ^3.9.7 => 3.9.7
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you reference? It's difficult to provide help if we can't see the code that produced the error.

Comment: Solved. Apparently I was really burned out. I was saving my file as `.ts` not as `.tsx`, that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is telling you you have a component that exists with similar with the same types, so you have to recheck your component, or probably you installed a package with similar name. It’s more of a type error from the programmer’s end.

Comment: This part is incomprehensible: *"exists with similar with the same types"*

Comment: slight English blunder thanks @PeterMortensen